# Two or more __in filters in django queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have this query

```
query = 'select * from products where (productnr, supplier_id) in (%s)' % product_list
```

where product_list looks like this ((OB520, 3),(RH402, 20)...)

How do I go about doing this in Django using queryset and the __in filter

Answer (score 7):

What part of this is confusing? http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/querysets/#in It seems very clear.

It's not perfectly clear from the question what the problem is.

Are you asking how to use a multi-part key?  If so, you're going to be unhappy with simple `__in`.

If you're trying to look for an "OR" of a two-part key, you have to create a more complex condition.

Start here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

```
from django.db.models import Q
product_list.filter(
Q(productnr='OB520', supplier_id=3) | Q(productnr='RH402', supplier_id=20))
```

If you're trying to do multi-key lookups, this is they way it has to work.

Or, is the problem that your "in" clause has a long list of specific values?

If you have a long list, you might want to build the query in pieces.

```
q_obj= Q()
for p, s in some_list_of_pairs;
   q_obj |= Q(productnr=p, supplier_id=s )
product_list.filter(q_obj)
```

The above is untested.  Also, it's probably inefficient.

What's better is something like this.

```
def values_iter( some_list_of_pairs ):
    for p, s in some_list_of_pairs
        yield product_list.get(productnr=p, supplier_id=s)
```

That will do a number of very efficient SQL lookups one at a time.  That may execute faster than building a complex multi-key IN clause.

Comment: The question isn't clear? Really? The question is straightforward. HOW DO YOU USE THE __in FILTER WITH TWO OR MORE FIELDS/VALUES? The product list can span up to 3000 items.

Comment: @Bingimar: "The product list can span up to 3000 items"?  Is that in the question?  I don't see it.  You can claim it's clear.  It's your question, of course you understand it.  Interesting, I'm not you.  To me, it's not clear.  I'm not a thin, not as smart and not as good-looking.  You can repeat the question.  Or you can **update** the question to help people like me understand it.  Repeating it doesn't seem helpful.  Expanding and explaining, and including **all** the facts seems helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Comma-delimit the query.

Example:

```
?groups__in=1,2
```

Sometimes it's better to answer the question rather than to bicker about it being a valid question.

Comment: Also, I believe depending on where you use this, you may need to split out the string then pass in the array like so:

`groups__in_val = request.GET['groups__in']`
`groups = groups__in_val.split(',')`

then in your filter:
`groups__in=groups`