# Django slow working. filtering by multiple params

Tags: django, multiple-choice

I have 3 models:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    title = CharField()

class Genre(models.Model):
    title = CharField()

class Book(models.Model):
    title = CharField()
    author = ManyToManyField(Author)
    genre = ManyToManyField(Genre)
```

And I have a checkbox form (multiple choice) with all Genres and Authors, where checkbox value is item (genre or author) id.

**Purpose:** Show books with selected authors or genres (without duplicates)

I can do this in two ways:

**First way:**

```
if request.POST:
    book_list = Book.objects.all() #get all books from db
    books = []  

    request_list = request.POST.getlist('genre') #select list of genres in request
        for item in request_list:
            add_book = report_list.filter(genre=r_request) #queryset of book filtered by each genre 
            books.append(add_book) 
            book_list = book_list.exclude(genre=item)

    request_list = request.POST.getlist('author') #select list of authors in request
        for item in request_list:
            add_book = report_list.filter(author=item) #queryset of book filtered by each author 
            books.append(add_book) 
            book_list = book_list.exclude(author=item)
    return ...
        'books': books
```

But this way is **very slow** when I select a lot of authors and genres, becouse excluding is very slow.

**Second way:**

Remove **book_list = book_list.exclude(...)** and apply template tag {% ifchanged book.id %}

But I think, this will be very slow too when I'll get 1000+ books in request result (books)

**How can I show books with selected authors and genres fast?**

Comment: Checkout `django-toolbar`.  It'll help you spot these kind of db performance issues early.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looping through a list, and for each one of the items in the list you're asking for an SQL query.

Each SQL query runs over the entire table database to get the results (unless it's organized properly).

So, you can use the [**__in**](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/querysets/#in) lookup to filter from a list:

"books that have authors from list **and** genres from list"

```
genre_list= request.POST.getlist('genre')
author_list = request.POST.getlist('author')
books = Book.objects.filter(genre__in=genre_list,author__in=author_list)
```

"books that have the genre **or** the author"

```
from django.db.models import Q
genre_list= request.POST.getlist('genre')
author_list = request.POST.getlist('author')
books = Book.objects.filter(Q(genre__in=genre_list) | Q(author__in=author_list))
```

You can also read [Two or more __in filters in django queryset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600402/two-or-more-in-filters-in-django-queryset) ... They use Q object to concatenate the query into one filter.

Comment: and if I want to choice few genres and few authors?

Comment: try Book.objects.filter(genre__in=genre_list,author__in=author_list)

Comment: not work when genre_list or author_list is empty (author_list = [] and genre_list = [u'32', u'24', u'19']) - returns empty queryset

Comment: Are you trying to do a "AND" or "OR" query ? This does an "AND" query, so because one of them is empty there's no match for the author.

Comment: I need "OR". I want to get all books which have one of the selected params

Comment: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'QuerySet' and 'QuerySet'

Comment: right, my bad, it's a QuerySet, not a list... Fixed the example to use Q queries

Comment: Thanks! All works. I added a **.distinct()** to remove duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

On my opinion:

```
genre_list= request.POST.getlist('genre')
author_list = request.POST.getlist('author')

query = None

if gender_list:
    gender_q = Q(genre__in=genre_list)
    query = gender_q

if author_list:
    author_q = Q(author__in=author_list)
    if gender_list:
       query|=author_q
    else:
       query = author_q

books = []
if query:
   books = Book.objects.filter(query).distinct()
```

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects